# Azure Devops Dashboards table

Tags: azure, azure-devops, dashboard

I need to display a table that has the following. Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STTgf.png)

for each team member total number of hours worked on a bug or task group by user story

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure where do you want to display this info, but DevOps offers you have some posibilities. First of all you can make a Query. There are inside Boards -> Queries. There you can build a query of whatever you need, PBI, Tasks, bugs, hours... The first time migth be a bit trickie, but you have several posibilities.

In adition if you want to have a pretier visualization, you can show this info in the dashbord, located in Overview -> Dashboards. There you add a new dashboard or edit an existing one, and add a new widget as the next picture:

[image]

Then you can configure the widget with the query you did. You must set the query as shared fore this.